# Grails domain beforeInsert / beforeUpdate

Tags: grails, insert, grails-domain-class

I want to save my domain class to the database without specifying the `createdUser` or `createdDate`. I’ve created an object called `AuditingInfo` and embedded it in the main `Person` domain class like this:

`AuditingInfo.groovy`:

```
class AuditingInfo {
    static constraints = {
        createdUser (nullable : true)
        updatedUser (nullable : true)
        createdDate(nullable : true)
        updatedDate(nullable : true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        columns {
            createdUsercolumn: 'T_CREATED_USER'
            updatedUsercolumn: 'T_UPDATED_USER'
            createdDatecolumn: 'T_CREATED_DATE'
            updatedDatecolumn: 'T_UPDATED_USER'
        }
    }

    User createdUser
    User updatedUser
    Date createdDate
    Date updatedDate
}
```

`Person.groovy`:

```
class Person {
    static embedded = ['auditingInfo']
    AuditingInfo auditingInfo

    static constraints = { auditingInfo(nullable: true) }
    String name
    Long id
}
```

I cannot use the `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate` events in the `Person` domain or `AuditingInfo` class, because it always causes a `NullPointerException` in `org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener`.
Therefore, I want to use the `metaClass` way, as used below (this action is defined in a `*GrailsPlugin.groovy` file, but unfortunately my project is a Grails project, not a Grails plugin project):

```
def doWithDynamicMethods = { ctx ->       
    application.domainClasses.each { org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClass gc ->
        gc.metaClass.beforeInsert = {
        }

        gc.metaClass.beforeUpdate = {
        }
    }
}
```

How can I apply this method to my project context? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply your metaClass modifications from within your Bootstrap.groovy, which is executed at start-up.

Answer (score 2):

agree with doelleri

just add your code :

```
application.domainClasses.each { org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClass gc ->
                    gc.metaClass.beforeInsert = {
                    }
                    gc.metaClass.beforeUpdate = {
                    }
        }
```

Into BootStrap.groovy