# How can I call a method on save and update of multiple domains?

Tags: grails, groovy, save

I want to call a service method for every `update` and `save` action of a bunch of different domain classes. I can call the method from `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate`, but there are many domains, and doing this for each one would be time-consuming. So is there any way around this? For example, adding

```
static transactional = true
```

to a service or controller makes the process transactional; so in a similar way, can I do something regarding this?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280340/grails-domain-beforeinsert-beforeupdate

Comment: You can register a separate event listener object that will listen for events from all domain classes, see the "Custom event listeners" subsection under [events and auto timestamping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) in the user guide.

Comment: I am trying to implement custom event listeners but I cannot find enough documentations regarding it, can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking:

Within the loop that is updating or saving your group of domains, call your service method and then call `save()`, setting the `flush` option to `false`:

```
.save(flush: false)
```

After you iterate through your group, run `.flush()` and `.clear()` on your session. (This will only flush your records once. You could also stick a counter in your loop and call `flush()` and `clear()` for every x number of records.)

Comment: no, this is not what i am looking for, but thanks for the response