# Grails event methods added in BootStrap no longer invoked after upgrade to 2.3.5

Tags: grails, groovy

In our Grails 2.2.3 application we add event handling methods to all domain classes by adding to the metaclasses in BootStrap.groovy init like so:

```
 for(gc in grailsApplication.domainClasses) {
     gc.metaClass.beforeInsert = {
         //our code
     }
     gc.metaClass.beforeUpdate = {
         //our code
     }
 }
```

(as inspired by this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9289678/1877147)

This works fine in 2.2.3 but no longer works after upgrading to 2.3.5. The methods are added to the metaclasses but never invoked. From the documentation it doesn't look like those event methods have been removed or changed or anything. Is there a different way to do this that will work in 2.3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BuildConfig, we switched to use maven as the dependency resolver instead of Ivy and now this problem no longer occurs.